# Установка языка сайта в зависимости от куки

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Реализовал несколько языков на сайте. При выборе языка, последний выбранный загружаю в куки.
Сам же вопрос состоит в том, как мне в зависимости от языка в куки загружать сразу нужный язык.
Стандартно django выдает язык в зависимости от локали. Как получить куки в бекэнде я знаю, но как при переходе на любой `url` сделать "переадресацию" на нужный язык.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать сессии.

Храните последний выбранный язык в сессии так:

`request.session['language'] = 'выбранный язык'`.

Далее в любом views получайте его так:

`language = request.session.get('language')`.

В сессии под нужным ключом вы храните значение, которое потом можете получить или изменить где угодно. И исходя из полученного или неполученного значения уже выполнять нужные вам действия. [Django session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/).